# Aggregate initialization with std::array within aggregate and interaction with datatype with implicit cast operator?

Tags: c++, c++20

According to cppreference, an aggregate containing aggregates can use brace elision such that:

```
struct outer1
{
    int x;
    struct
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    } inner;
};
```

OR

```
struct outer1
{
    int x;
    int y[2];
};
```

Then the type can be constructed with `outer1{0,1,2}` or `outer1{0,{1,2}}` and result in the same value.

Also according to cppreference, `std::array` is an aggregate.  Thus if `inner` is instead an `array<int,2>`:

```
struct outer2
{
    int x;
    std::array<int,2> y;
};
```

then the same statements work and I can initialize with `outer2{0,1,2}` or `outer{0,{1,2}}`.

So far, so good.  Aggregates that hold aggregates can be initialized with or without the braces around the inner aggregate initializer values.

However, if I use a type declared as so:

```
struct any
{
    template < typename T >
    constexpr operator T () noexcept;
};
```

Then while `outer2{0,1,2}`, `outer2{0,{1,2}}`, and `outer2{any(), {any(), any()}}` work, `outer2{any(), any(), any()}` does not and results in a "too many initializers" error.

And yet, `outer1{any(),any(),any()}` is fine with both versions of `outer1` when I expect the same exact rules to apply to all three.

[On godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISdKuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIACsAJykAA6oCoRODB7evv7SaRmOAiFhkSwxcUm2mPbFDEIETMQEOT5%2BATV1WY3NBKUR0bEJyQpNLW15nWN9A%2BWVIwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1Cbbbs3ETACeJ9gmGgCCO3sHmMenTmPEmKw3d48PBEwLBSBkBbzchwIlxSjFYrwAKm9bg80AwxpgAG5iQ5RVCeQ6oz5eBxMKL0AD6oQIEEWfxMAHYrA9DizDl8CGsGGzMABHLx4L4KBkWQ7w4UaUhcUhmBkAEROIrlCrp9PlDz%2BRIch0M13VjL%2BrMhQJBTDBJwhUJhzDYopux2ZrNQMIuRGIosONIJAjGhwYqEwqg2KQIyr18u2TP%2B90BwNBr3NkOhsJtiN%2BKO9gKxtBxeOzhIIxGJTTJmHJOppKsjhvZnO5fIFmAUx0ZtsZ5eW2oYlxppE73dpqoVzfDkaV6oemoIhywxBSlYNrLG6BAIHOV3NVN72ztqlDj0HEbpE4LRcOCFic71VdZVMOu/iFm38RHKpf4/uk8OAHcNCGrwuWVvXdDwdQDBEOa4HxlZ89yVECo0/H8Z0vfdrzAqdgLQw4lxXNdrneQRpTtfDRwPUcHlvFgmFCCt/1A7CCGXFBVinc0E3zQsSRLSlBHNZCbk9NjTmOMxoLcBhzBleDDRw5ivFY052IzTjiwpHU%2BIvATFnBBNJJMeJxL06TF0Ylc0HknThI4otSQpKlzXPWctMsiE9IMiTRL3GTTLkhS3CUtETy4tSuwczTtmwQTFOEtzDM84yWVk8y/ICydbNLezTh/EMIqi/yYs89yjKwpKWJcr1ApU9Ky1CrLf2coTXMKuKpJKnzkvK6zgoy3i6v43LtMakSxI81qAIYpiOqGrrVNLdS%2BvCyLBuipqRuKo97kNLB9ktTAIGy8VJSI1VtKYLzWW22hdv2%2Bq2y7Ht21Ids5W0qJYPoy7rqQzTGQlKUZROglzpZAB6EHPqTG7%2BLu/snvu5ZnsB9AhzBw4qGo2ghXfQ1UYsOQxQ%2BzAdsh2S8I3QipNuGGez7CtAcwWDVQ4ZZaE4eJeD8DgtFIVBOH8yxrGw1Z1njMxth4UgCE0ZnlgAawSLgADptg0eJtgANi4FW1c18X9E4SQOelnnOF4BQQAlKWueZ0g4FgJAAyJ%2BSSHIShmmABRlEMWohAQVAv05iW0GBOhTSyL2wloX3/c57ng5SOhhmALgpFIePE%2BIcI4VNtPUBD%2BhiAAeXk6OA%2BNx3kHuYgPZzivGnwTneH4QQRDEdhU%2Bb%2BQlDUY3dClAwjBQaxrH0PAonNyBlidepzY4ABaJcTllUwBcsMwNEOOfC%2B2XhUAxWJiDwLAJ57QtBDwNh4VzE/lgUYWNj0JdQgjn2/bL7heALTB2AlL8LhSTgPAWZsyNtbE2HBsCqCdq6O8AAOdWc91aSEOMAZAyBDgp0VsgiA/MrCWF7LgQgJARLi0WJ/aWiw5b%2BFgYrdWiRJDq22PA%2BhjDmH6w4IbUgsdd453NpbChwCOBmFAdzXmHByHW0oaQfexAMjOEkEAA%3D%3D)

What are the rules that cause this?  Is cppreference wrong in some way or have I missed something?  What other cases of aggregates having sub-aggregates might this same issue show up?

Comment: In `outer2{any(), any(), any()}` second `any()` will be implicitly converted to array to initialize `outer2::y` therefore it produces "too many initializers" error. If you replace template `operator T` with plain `operator int` then it will work as indented.

Comment: As always, initialization in c++ is overly complicated.

Comment: OK, I thought I saw this working with `outer1` inner struct version.  The any DOES get converted to the inner struct in the same way and the constructor fails for the same reason.  My hallucinations got the best of me again.  I wouldn't have needed to ask this because that's what I thought was happening but didn't understand why not struct.  Well, struct.  So there you go.

Comment: Note for others: The reason it works with array version is that you can only initialize a raw array with braces and if you do that with `any` it'll assume you mean to initialize the first element.  There's no ambiguity there for language rules to further resolve and so you can use either form to initialize the outer struct.  You can't do `int x[2](any())` nor `int x[2] = any{}` -- neither is a valid form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"too many initializers" error* - the second `any()` is converted to `std::array<int,2> y;`, the third `any()` exceeds the number of elements in `outer2`.